# Windows 10: Can't ping or connect to a few specific IP addresses

Tags: windows, networking

I can connect to everywhere else just fine. I can resolve the DNS to the correct IP. Other devices on the same network, wired and wireless, can connect to these sites without trouble.

Even more confusing, a Linux VM running on the problem machine can connect. I've actually been using `socat` on that host to proxy my connections, and then it works!

But it's been slowly spreading to more hosts, and some of them I can't configure to use that workaround.

`ping` times out, and so does `tracert`. Only Windows firewall is running, and it doesn't have any rules about these hosts. Pretty vanilla home network.

Answer (score 1):

Several things have can be checked:

- disable the firewall to see if anything change
- check the routing table, and check if tracert display the same path as on other computers
- check the MTU with `netsh interface ip show interface` (probably not, because ping use small packets and it fails too)